# Cómo puedo usar el window.onscroll 2 veces en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Al parecer hay un error y no me deja tener 2 window.onscroll de esta manera, solo me sale una de las dos funciones al hacer scroll hacia abajo.

```
let ubicacionPrincipal = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  let Desplazamiento_Actual = window.pageYOffset;
  if(ubicacionPrincipal >= Desplazamiento_Actual){
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '0';
  } else {
      document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '-110px';
  }
  ubicacionPrincipal = Desplazamiento_Actual;
}

window.onscroll = function () {
  let scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
if (scroll > 600) {
    buttonUp.style.transform = "scale(1)";
} else if (scroll < 600) {
    buttonUp.style.transform = "scale(0)";
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Y no puedes combinarlos en una misma función? Al fin y al cabo no usan nada en común que pueda dar problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor manera de enlazar funciones es dándoles un nombre, e invocándolas después con un `addEventListener`. Por ejemplo, en tu caso podría ser:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  NavbarStyle();
  buttonUpStyle();
});

let ubicacionPrincipal = window.pageYOffset;
function NavbarStyle() /*cambia el nombre de la función a uno que te resulte descriptivo*/ {
  let Desplazamiento_Actual = window.pageYOffset;
  if (ubicacionPrincipal >= Desplazamiento_Actual) {
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '0';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '-110px';
  }
  ubicacionPrincipal = Desplazamiento_Actual;
}

function buttonUpStyle() /*cambia el nombre de la función a uno que te resulte descriptivo*/ {
  let scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (scroll > 600) {
    buttonUp.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  } else if (scroll < 600) {
    buttonUp.style.transform = "scale(0)";
  }
}
```

Este método te permite enlazar tantas funciones como quieras a un mismo evento, sin que se sobrescriban unas a otras. ;)

Comment: Excelente solución!